# How to start for loop for a list at different starting index instead of [0]?

Tags: python-3.x, list, for-loop, indexing

```
#creating a list named employees 

print(('#'*50).center(100,'~'))

employees=[['Name','Age','Department'],['John Mckee',28,'Sales'],['Lisa Crawford',29,'Marketing'],['Sujan patel',33,'HR']]

#print the top row of the matrix (the column names)

print(employees[0],'\n')

print('LISA DETAILS'.center(100,'-'))

#print only lisa details 

print('Name:',employees[2][0])
print('Age:',employees[2][1])
print('Department:',employees[2][2])



#print all employees details 

print('ALL DETAILS'.center(100,'-'))

print(employees)

#want to start for loop at Name:John,Age:28,Department:sales, instead of Name:Name,Age:Age,Department:Department 

for e in (employees):
        print('Name:',e[0])
        print('Age:',e[1])
        print('Department:',e[2])
```

Any way that I can start printing from second row (the employees basically) instead of first row (Name, Age, Department)?

I do, not know how I would go on about approaching for loop within a list at different position.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need more pythonic approach to what @pakpe presented you can use list slicing

```py
for e in employees[from_index:to_index]:
  ...
```

where `from_index` and `to_index` indicate boundaries and one of them may be omitted if not needed. This creates a copy of the array however. If you don't want to make copies then use `itertools.islice()`

```py
for e in islice(employees, from_index, to_index):
  ...
```

unused parameter should be explicitly set to `None` in this case.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I learnt new methods which I always appreciate.

Comment: Also, consider using `collections.namedtuple` to store data.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using a for-each loop, use a regular for loop that advances the index from 1 to len(employees):

```
for i in range(1, len(employees)):
    print('Name:',employees[i][0])
    print('Age:',employees[i][1])
    print('Department:',employees[i][2])
```

Comment: To be pedantic, this is *still* a "for each" loop, there *is not other kind of for loop in Python*. You are simply looping over a `range` object instead of over the `list` object.

Comment: list index out of range.  print('Age:',[e][1]).